# Get profit center/cost center from RBKP invoice receipt number

Tags: abap, sap-erp

How can I get the cost center, profit center? I am from RSEG and RBKP tables is there any other way to get those, I can't use vbseg tables cause the doc no. are stored in RSEG and RBKP since I created the document using MIR7. please help. thanks

Comment: What data do you have? Full key from `RBKP` and `RSEG`? And wanna get profit center (`PRCTR`) and cost center (`COSTL`)?

Comment: have the document number or belnr from rseg, how can I get the PRCTR and KOSTL? do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should  find accounting document number from invoice number (RBKP-BELNR). You can do this by two ways:

1. Via reference key (AWKEY). You should concatenate fields `BELNR` and `GJAHR` and link this with BKPF-AWKEY.

[image]

2. Another way to find this number is via GUI. Enter your RBKP-BELNR into MIRO transaction and press *Follow-on documents*, here you will see it as well.

[image]

After finding that BKPF number take it along with full key and go to `BSEG`. You will find cost center there (`KOSTL` field).

Profit centers can be found by cost centers from `CSKS` link-table.

Comment: I tried both of the method you instructed, but it doesn't work.  i tried to concatenate the belnr and the gjahr but there's no data. btw i made the document in MIR7 Tcode.

Comment: what means 'no data'? no data in BKPF? and  what shows MIRO?

Comment: the document number given in miro does not exist in bkpf or bseg. i filtered the bkpf using the given doc no in the miro but no data was shown.

Comment: Bullshit. This cannot be, 'cause all accounting documents are stored in `BKPF`. Did you copy exactly accounting doc number, not any other follow-on doc (there are plenty of them)? Does your screenshot looks like mine?

Comment: Quick reminder that swearing words are discouraged ;)

Comment: i got it! thanks @Suncatcher , You're a legend. Thank you!!