# How can I link RSEG table into BSEG or RBKP to BSEG?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I already browse the web but i find no answer that can solve my problem.

I tried the concatenation of `RBKP-BELNR` and `RBKP-GJAHR` into `BKPF-AWKEY` to get the `BKPF-BELNR` then `BKPF-BELNR` to `BSEG-BELNR`, but always show no records.

I need to link to the `RSEG` to `BSEG` or `RBKP` to `BSEG` .

Need some help! thanks!

Edit: I made the parked document in Tcode MIR7

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743731/get-profit-center-cost-center-from-rbkp-invoice-receipt-number), but can't enter to VBSEGS table.

**UPDATE**: these are the details I want to get. but can't find the other details

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Comment: Parked Invoice don't generate BSEG registers, this will be generate when you efective the document.

Comment: But do you have any idea on how the simulate button display all the data in the table control, or at least the flow?

Is it possible to replicate the flow and get all the records same with data diplayed on simulate?

Comment: `can't enter to RSEG table` what means you can't enter? [In my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747750/911419) I described how to find BKPF number from RBKP, and RSEG is nothing but item table for RBKP. It's quite trivial.

Comment: @Suncatcher sorry VBSEGS table, not RSEG. My mistake. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate BELNR & GJAHR from RSEG and pass it to the AWKEY field of BKPF table and you will get Accounting document number "BELNR", year "GJAHR" & Company Code "BUKRS". Pass these fields to BSEG and you will get the other details. Did you try it exactly this way? You should check your belnr has left padding '0' you can check it with double click on the record in SE16n tcode.[image]

Actually, you can directly link these table.
[image]
Last option, If these are still not working for you, then you can link: However, it will kill the performance, I believe.

```
RSEG-EBELN = BSEG-EBELN
RSEG-EBELP = BSEG-EBELP
RSEG-MATNR = BSEG-MATNR
```

Comment: I' tried them all, same step as you said, but bseg always return with no values found.

Comment: Or is there any function module I can use in  getting the details?

Answer (score 0):

I think is this:

```
RSEG-LFBNR = BSEG-BELNR
RSEG-LFGJA = BSEG-GJAHR
RSEG-LFPOS = BSEG-BUZEI
```

Comment: RSEG doesn't have LFBNR

Comment: hmm I'm on SAP 7.50 here we have this fields

Comment: For older versions you can use BKPF-AWKEY, how you said, this work here on older versions.

Comment: I already tried the awkey to get the accounting document number from, bkpf but then linked it with bseg but always return no values found.