# Getting all the line items in MIR7

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Getting all the line items that is displayed during the simulation in Tcode MIR7.

This is my old post, still have no Idea and answer how. 
Tried looking in every table, and I tried everything they suggested here:

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50346420/9750247)

Comment: You wrote: "during simulation". As long as the document is simulated only, it is not saved anywhere. Saved will be, when you post the document (by clicking Save). After posting, the MM invoice will be stored in RBKP (header) and RSEG (items)

Comment: Why are you looking for the data, only in the simulation? If you need to check something on invoice documents, you should use the exits/badis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I link RSEG table into BSEG or RBKP to BSEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346420/how-can-i-link-rseg-table-into-bseg-or-rbkp-to-bseg)

Comment: Don't multiply your own questions, if it is not answered there, it's unlikely will be answered here.